# Sublime text: How to disable automatching 'quotes'

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Here's my problem: In common lisp, a 'single quote' is not used for strings and thus doesn't come in pairs with another quote, so sublime text auto-inserting another quote does more harm than good. How do I disable that option *just for lisp* and just for single quotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a keybinding to your keymap (which you can find in preferences, key bindings) and in the user tab paste this:

```json
{
  "keys": ["'"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "'"},
  "context":
  [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.lisp" }
  ]
},
```

Let me know if you need anything else! I tested it in sublime text (I use it too)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

If you go into Preferences > Settings on Sublime Text 3, you should see various preferences that you can control manually. This line controls the auto-pairing of quotes:

```
// Controls auto pairing of quotes, brackets etc
"auto_match_enabled": true,
```

To overwrite it, add `"auto_match_enabled": false`, to the right pane (user prefs) between the brackets and save to update your preferences. If you already have preferences in the right pane, be sure to separate with a ',' like with json properties.